# Script to change all triggers in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the problem that all the triggers in a MS SQL database contains the old SQL 2000 syntax like:

```sql
raiserror 99999 'ErrorMsg'
```

This causes error. The correct should be:

```
raiserror ('ErrorMsg',16,1)
```

The text 'ErrorMsg' is different in different triggers (about 45 variants). The thing is, there are 123 triggers and 185 occurrences that needs to be corrected in the database.

It is possible to script out each trigger, delete it, correct the syntax and re-create it. 123 times :-(

So - I am looking for a script that can loop through the triggers and correct all occurrences of raiserror 99999. The script should be smart enough to keep the 'ErrorMsg' for each trigger.

Comment: You should be using `THROW` now anyway, so rather than updating to a different unrecommended syntax, switch to the "correct" one. This means you need to address each of your triggers yourself; there is no magic "make my triggers work in modern versions of SQL Server" feature.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS [generate a single script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16) for all the triggers, then in the SSMS query editor use [Find and Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/find-and-replace?view=sql-server-ver16) to make the changes.

You can spend time to write clever regular expressions with Find and Replace, or since there are only "185 occurrences" just jump down through the script and change each one by hand.  Sometimes you'll end up doing some combination of the two.  EG a regular expression to find and replace common cases, and manual changes for other cases.

Comment: Well, what I hope is not to do 185 manual updates, but it might turn out to be the simplest way. This is an old database and system that is to be decommissioned, so there is no use to modernize it. The purpose is just to extract all data and shut it down.